# If a topological subspace that is simply connected is extended by a path, is it still simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If a topological subspace $Y$ of $X$ is simply connected (but $X$ isn't) and we extended $Y$ with a path, meaning we take the union of $Y$ and a path from a point in $Y$ to a point in $X$ outside $Y$ (in a straight line, or at least not in a loop), is the extension of $Y$ then also simply connected?

I think so because the extension is still path connected and all loops with portions of the path in it is still be homotopic to the trivial loop?

but how to prove this in formal way?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Consider the unit open ball around the origin in $\mathbb R^2$, which is clearly simply connected. Extend a path from $(0,0)\to(1,0)$ that goes to $(0,1)$, then to $(1,1)$, then to $(1,0)$ in straight segments. This new domain isn't simply connected, as the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$ is a closed curve that can't be reduced to a point.

**Edit**: OP wants an example with a straight path, the picture below illustrates an example:

[image]

Another example:  Let $B(x,r)$ be the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Consider $C=B((0,0),2)\setminus\overline{B((0,0),1)}$ and the path $(1.5,0)\to(-1,0)$

Comment: sorry i was not specific enough. I mean the path must be in straight line or at least not form a loop.  in your example, the path forms a loop that goes from (1, 0) to (0, 1) to (1, 1) and then to (1,0).

Comment: @Loli That doesn't change anything. The simply connected set can be like a lima bean.

Comment: I think i don't understand. if I extend the unit disc with the path from (1, 0) to (1, 2), then the extended space (disc plus the path) is clearly simply connected no?

Comment: @Loli See the picture.

Comment: and I think the reason it works is because the path is in straight line. But will it work for any space?

Comment: The picture doesn't work because the path is going from the subspace back into the subspace. the question is about when the path goes from the subspace to *outside* the subspace.

Comment: @Loli It isn't going back in. The point on the bottom is on the border of the space.

Comment: ah, so the space is open. I see thank you. Last question: is this the only case in which it doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, it's just the easiest example to visualize. Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: ok, i'm trying to find a 'perfect' set up in which it could work, so your answer has been helpful to narrow it down. thanks

Comment: I don't know what that means, but as stated, this answer more than resolves your question

Comment: it means I'm trying to find the conditions that will allow me to extend a simply connected subspace with a path from it to a point outside it such that the resulting extended space is still simply connected. what makes the problem difficult is that, the subspace is arbitrary. All we know is that it's simply connected.  surely, it's not *always* impossible to obtain this construction.

Comment: That's not the question you asked, though. And if you asked that question, it would immediately be closed since that's not well defined as a problem. To me, it seems like you need to think harder about the things you want before asking. The question is, does this answer THIS question, not the one in your head.

Comment: yes it has. don't worry i will accept your answer once i'm sure there will be no more contribution on this post. like I said, thanks for the help

Comment: so your response it then to create a close vote... i'm not even going to try understand why.

Comment: @Loli Because your question is too broad

Comment: Right :)  tbh it doesn't bother me if you close it. i'm grateful for your answer, but i think your attitude afterwards is childish.

Comment: @Loli I don't appreciate the name-calling. I view what you are doing as quite improper, and I'm using the tools of the site to express that. I'm not asking that you accept this answer, but the reasons why you don't do so are truly troubling. It's obvious that you don't have a respect for the users who spend time to answer your questions.

Comment: Since the very start, you've been moving the goal posts. Oh, I didn't mean this, I didn't mean that. That's not an appropriate way of asking a question on this site, which is aimed at being a resource for people other than you.

Comment: that's not true. I edited the question only once. it happens to forget a detail in a question and then add it afterwards. I'm very grateful for your time, as I've repeatedly said it. anyways, never mind. let's both of us go and find something more useful to do :)